# How do Time of Flight (ToF) cameras work

Tags: distance-measurement

I have a question about [Time of Flight (ToF) cameras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-flight_camera). I understand how ToF cameras work with a single point but I can't understand how ToF cameras determinate from which point of scene do pulses from. For example if, a ToF camera uses a diode highlight then it will cover multiple objects on scene.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the receiver (camera) can only determine the signal's source to the limit of the field of view (FOV) of the lens + pixel system.  That is, the lens produces an image on the detector plane, and each pixel thus collects all the light (or radiation) sourced from objects within the horizontal and vertical angular FOV of that pixel.

Radar systems, lacking any physical "lens" , generally perform phase comparisons across antenna "patches" aka sub-antenna sections to estimate the most likely angular direction of the incoming radiation.

It is true that if your setup had no lens , you would not be able to determine the direction from which the light originated.